# ERROR with Prestashop HOOK and sliders (displayhomeafter) - Slider Revolution/AN Theme Blocks

Tags: css, module, slider, prestashop, hook

When I put slider with Slider Revolution/An Theme Blocks (Prestashop modules that creates images to use in a hook of the site) here ( [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nasj.jpg) ) the banner don't use all the space in the sides (it don't expands to all the width as you can see). I tried to change the dimensions and other configurations in the modules but when I put the banner in displayhomeafter that happens and in displayhomesliderfullwidth (another hook) it works. I think it's a code error. Can you help?

I tried to change the dimensions of the image, the type of banner in Slider Revolution and other configurations inside Slider Revolution and it didn't work in that hook (in the other hook I mentioned yes). The modules I mentioned in the other message are in Prestashop - Design - Positions (of the module) and hooked in displayhomeafter (the position where I have problems). The version of Prestashop is 1.7.7.5 and as a said the fail is in that hook: displayhomeafter. The hook is added to Slider Revolution and An Theme Blocks. The theme of Prestashop is Ledonia and the developer is Anvanto Team.

Thanks